# JUnit EasyMock unexpected method call expected 1 actual 0

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have problem with JUnit testing one method. I use EasyMock.createMock to mock someDao. 
I still get `easymock unexpected method call expected 1 actual 0  someDato.findByCriteria(criteria, -1, -1)`
That's how code looks like (it's only draft).
I suspect that problem is in `criteria` object.
The error points line `return someDato.findByCriteria(criteria, -1, -1);`

```
@Test
public void findDataSericeTest(){
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(SomeClass.class);
    criteria.add(Restictions.eq("sth1",string1));
    criteria.add(Restictions.eq("sth2",string2));

    expect(someDato.findByCriteria(criteria, -1, -1)).andReturn(SomeClass);
    replay(someDao);
    serviceTested.findDataService("string1","string2");

    EasyMock.verify(someDao);

}

 public SomeClass findDataService(String string1, String string2){
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(SomeClass.class);
    criteria.add(Restictions.eq("sth1",string1));
    criteria.add(Restictions.eq("sth2",string2));

    return someDato.findByCriteria(criteria, -1, -1);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet `DetachedCriteria` does not implement / override `equals` and `hashcode`. The verification will use the `equals` method of the expected argument to see if it matches the actual argument passed.

Comment: I had idea to use `expect(someDato.findByCriteria(isA(DetachedCriteria.class, isA(Integer.class), isA(Integer.class)).andReturn(SomeClass);` but I was getting NullPointerException in this line

Comment: try `isA(DetachedCriteria.class), eq(-1), eq(-1)`. If that doesn't work post the attempt

Comment: Also, did you try implementing `equals` in `DetachedCriteria`?

Comment: I will be able to check this solution tomorrow (with eq()), but I'm not sure why should I implement additional methods in Hibernate DetachedCriteria class?

Comment: Didn't know that `DetachedCriteria` was a Hibernate class. Looking at the javadocs for it it does not appear that they overrode `equals` so using anything other than `isA` is out. You should be good with `isA`.

Comment: `isA(DetachedCriteria.class), eq(-1), eq(-1)` that was correct way